# Similarity and Difference between Separable Space and Separated space?

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms, separable-spaces, second-countable

Does separability and/or second countability implies $T_2$ or higher axiom sets?

My intuition is "no". Even $T_0$ space can be separability and/or second countability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider $X = \{a,b\}$ just two elements and $\mathcal{T} = \{\emptyset, X\}$. This is separable, second countable, and not even $T_0$.